# Checking voltage expectation of HP G3 UPS

Tags: ups

We have several HP G3 UPS's (most of them are [HP R1500 G3](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/power-protection/rackups/index.html)). Some of our UPS's were constantly going into Buck mode. Turns out their dip switches on the back were never changed from default, which was to expect an input voltage of 220V, and our circuits run on 240v (10a).

I'm wondering if there's a way to interrogate the UPS's expected voltage (manually via the web interface or via SNMP)?

I've dug all around the interface, but the only way I can see of checking it is by physically looking at the back of each UPS (which I don't want to have to do!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to do this programatically. I ended up squinting at the DIP switches on the back of each UPS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't *know* that it has this feature, but it's possible that you can get it from [NUT](http://networkupstools.org/).  Their [HCL](http://networkupstools.org/stable-hcl.html) says that HP provided them protocol docs for the R1500 G2, so there is some reasonable expectation that it might be there.  It also apparently uses the same protocol as Eaton UPSes, which might imply that they are rebranded Eatons, and Eaton sponsors the project to some extent.